# Expected type `&Vec<u8>`, found `&Vec<&u8>`

Tags: types, rust

I have this small snippet, but it does not compile and all the errors stem from the fact that [`combinations_n`](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.combinations_n) returns `&Vec<&u8>` instead of `&Vec<u8>`.

```
extern crate itertools;

use std::io;
use std::collections::BTreeMap;
use std::iter::Enumerate;
use itertools::Itertools;

const RANKS: [u8; 13] = [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];

fn is_straight(hand: &Vec<u8>) -> bool {
    for (i, h) in hand[1..].iter().enumerate() {
        if h - hand[i] != 1 {
            return false;
        }
    }
    true
}

fn hand_value(hand: &Vec<u8>) -> u8 {
    hand.iter().fold(0_u8, |a, &b| a + 2u8.pow(b as u32));
}

fn generate_flush_table() ->  BTreeMap<u8,u8> {
    let ft = BTreeMap::new();
    let mut straight_counter = 1;
    let mut other_counter = 323;
    for flush in RANKS.iter().combinations_n(5) {
        if flush == [12, 3, 2, 1, 0] {
            continue;
        } else if is_straight(&flush) {
            ft.insert(hand_value(&flush), straight_counter);
            straight_counter += 1;
        } else {
            ft.insert(hand_value(&flush), other_counter);
            other_counter += 1;
        }
    }
    ft
}


fn main() {
    let flush_table: BTreeMap<u8,u8> = generate_flush_table();
    for (key, value) in flush_table.iter() {
        println!("{}: {}", key, value);
    }
}
```

Here's what the compiler says:

```
error: the trait bound `&u8: std::cmp::PartialEq<_>` is not satisfied [E0277]
        if flush == [12, 3, 2, 1, 0] {
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0277` to see a detailed explanation
help: the following implementations were found:
help:   <u8 as std::cmp::PartialEq>
note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::PartialEq<[_; 5]>` for `std::vec::Vec<&u8>`
error: mismatched types [E0308]
        } else if is_straight(&flush) {
                              ^~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
note:    found type `&std::vec::Vec<&u8>`
error: mismatched types [E0308]
            ft.insert(hand_value(&flush), straight_counter);
                                 ^~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
note:    found type `&std::vec::Vec<&u8>`
error: mismatched types [E0308]
            ft.insert(hand_value(&flush), other_counter);
                                 ^~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `&std::vec::Vec<u8>`
note:    found type `&std::vec::Vec<&u8>`
```

I really don't understand how the type of `flush` could really be `&Vec<&u8>`, given that `combinations_n` returns a [`CombinationsN`](https://bluss.github.io/rust-itertools/doc/itertools/struct.CombinationsN.html) and in the documentation I read

```
impl<I> Iterator for CombinationsN<I>
    where I: Iterator,
          I::Item: Clone
{
    type Item = Vec<I::Item>
```

and so it should actually be a `Vec<u8>`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As a professional programmer, you should learn to produce a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](/help/mcve). Here is one for your problem:

```
extern crate itertools;
use itertools::Itertools;

const RANKS: [u8; 13] = [12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0];

fn main() {
    let one_combination: () = RANKS.iter().combinations_n(5).next();
}
```

Which fails with the related error:

```
error: mismatched types [E0308]
    let one_combination: () = RANKS.iter().combinations_n(5).next();
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
help: run `rustc --explain E0308` to see a detailed explanation
note: expected type `()`
note:    found type `std::option::Option<std::vec::Vec<&u8>>`
```

This shows that this *particular* call of `combinations_n` does produce a `Vec<&u8>`, not a `Vec<u8>`.

So why is that?

This line from the definition of `CombinationsN` is the key:

```
type Item = Vec<I::Item>
```

`CombinationsN` is an *iterator adaptor*, so `I::Item` is the type of the iterator that precedes it. In our case, what is that? An [`slice::Iter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/struct.Iter.html), which has this:

```
type Item = &'a T
```

So by iterating over a slice, you get references to the slice elements, and then the *reference itself* is passed to `CombinationsN`, which then clones *the reference* and collects it into a `Vec`.

One solution is to clone the iterated elements:

```
RANKS.iter().cloned().combinations_n(5)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually removed quite a bit of code and I thought that it was a sufficiently small example. I shall be more mindful in future. Also thank you for the detailed explanation.

Comment: @rubik no worries! I just tend to point out the smaller versions that can be created because there's usually a few more steps to slimming down an example. At least your question included enough information to actually reproduce the problem! ^_^